# Pass a date as an argument

Tags: java, sql, datetime

I did a SQL query in Java as follows:

```
"SELECT A.ID_MACHINE, A.HEURODATAGE, A.COMPTEUR, B.LIBELLE_IDMACHINE, C.LIBELLE_STATUT, C.CODE_COULEUR FROM ROXJAVA.MACH0004 A " +
"JOIN ROXJAVA.MACH0003 B ON A.ID_MACHINE = B.ID_MACHINE " +
"JOIN ROXJAVA.MACH0002 C ON B.CODE_MACHINE = C.CODE_MACHINE " +
"WHERE A.ID_MACHINE = ? AND A.HEURODATAGE BETWEEN '?' AND '?' AND A.CODE_STATUT = C.CODE_STATUT AND C.CODE_COULEUR = ? " +
"ORDER BY A.HEURODATAGE DESC";
```

In my WHERE it finds "Heurodatage" which must contain a time and a date with this format:

> '2018-07-03 09:30:00.000'

I then want to retrieve the results of this query with the help of a method that takes into account the different attributes that I need to replace the? in my request.

But now I can not determine the type of my dates.

I'm getting "type not match" when I try to run with a String.

Comment: `BETWEEN '?' AND '?'`should be `BETWEEN ? AND ?`, and the actual dat type is probably not a varchar but a date or a timestamp, so you should pass instances of java.sql.Timestamp as parameters to your prepared statement, not strings. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Still better, @JBNizet, provided that the one can use at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2, skip the outdated `Timestamp` class and use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. Depending on the exact datatype of the database column use for example `yourPreparedStatement.setObject(2, yourLocalDateTime);` (the passed Java object could be a `LocalDateTime` or an `Instant`).

Answer (score 0):

If the column is a date column, you want to pass in a date type:

```
PreparedStatement ps = ...;
ps.setDate(N, java.sql.Date.valueOf(your_date_value));
```

where it would be best if your_date_value is a java.time.LocalDate, but could also be parsed from a String (in a valid format).

Comment: If `your_date_value` is a `LocalDate` (which I agree to recommend for a date) and your JDBC driver is JDBC 4.2 compliant (which I believe most are these days), then just `ps.setObject(N, your_date_value);`. “Horodatage” means timestamping, so it’s probably rather a timestamp column, though. Call the same `setObject` method, only pass a different type.